# IntelliJ IDEA 12 and non-standard items in themes.xml

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Try to compile a project with [this](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker/) library.
IntelliJ IDEA 12 shows an error on non-standard elements in the themes.xml and dont compile.

Items:

```
<style name="SampleTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="numberPickerUpButtonStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.ImageButton.NumberPickerUpButton</item>
    <item name="numberPickerDownButtonStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.ImageButton.NumberPickerDownButton</item>
    <item name="numberPickerInputTextStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.EditText.NumberPickerInputText</item>
    <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.NumberPicker</item>
</style>
```

Errors:

```
android-apt-compiler: [samples] /Users/max/work/libs/android-numberpicker/samples/res/values/themes.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'numberPickerDownButtonStyle'.
android-apt-compiler: [samples] /Users/max/work/libs/android-numberpicker/samples/res/values/themes.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'numberPickerInputTextStyle'.
android-apt-compiler: [samples] /Users/max/work/libs/android-numberpicker/samples/res/values/themes.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'numberPickerStyle'.
android-apt-compiler: [samples] /Users/max/work/libs/android-numberpicker/samples/res/values/themes.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'numberPickerUpButtonStyle'.
```

This problem also appears if you use and other libraries.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Please check that you are using recent Android Platform for the project. In [Module Dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) there should be **4.0.x** or higher platform version:

[image: Android Platform]

Comment: I am using Android 4.2 Google APIs, and I am still facing this issue.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: please share a sample project that builds in the command line, but fails in IDEA.

Comment: The main cause of that problem is that attrs.xml needs to have the above-said style references.  Also, the included projects with these style references need to be set up as library projects in Idea.  Once that was done, the project built fine.  It wasn't the SDK version that caused this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define these attributes' types in the same styles file, as a child of `resources` node:

```
<attr name="numberPickerUpButtonStyle" format="reference" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by "child of resources node"?  I put that right under <resources>, and my other <item> tags started throwing compilation errors.

Comment: @Igor, in XML tree sense. Did you close the `resources` tag? Can you create a gist with your code?

Comment: basically these values need to be in attrs.xml.  That was the source of my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

- You should add android-calendarview library too (by SimonVT again) to the android-numberpicker module as a dependency
- Add these libraries as a dependency to your main module.
- Mark these added projects as a library project
- Add this style to your styles.xml what you use at your project. (you can change style too of course)

  ```
      <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.NumberPicker</item>
  ```

Comment: This led my to fix my problem, for some reason I had to delete and import the SimonVT numberPicker library again and delete and re-add the library. Now numberPickerStyle got recoqnized.

Answer (score 0):

Your library project is probably compiled as an application project. To change this, go to :

**File > Project structure > Facets > [Library name] >** Check "Library module".

Answer (score 0):

NumberPicker/DataPicker module should be set to SDK4.2